# PHP Amazon webservice uncaught curl exception

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I am trying to make a website to manage some files and links through amazon web service. I am new to this service and are having some problems at the moment. I am trying to setup my environment, but after reassuring all extension are enabled on my web server (curl, and all the others from http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4261?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1#configurecredentials) I still get an error in my apache error log:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #10; cURL error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:\nerror:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (cURL error code 60). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.' in C:\\www\\thorastrup\\client_app\\sdk-1.5.14\\lib\\requestcore\\requestcore.class.php:829\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\www\\thorastrup\\client_app\\sdk-1.5.14\\services\\s3.class.php(910): RequestCore->send_request()\n#1 C:\\www\\thorastrup\\client_app\\sdk-1.5.14\\services\\s3.class.php(1147): AmazonS3->authenticate('php-sdk-getting...', Array)\n#2 C:\\www\\thorastrup\\client_app\\sdk-1.5.14\\_samples\\cli-s3_get_urls_for_uploads.php(60): AmazonS3->create_bucket('php-sdk-getting...', 's3-us-west-1.am...')\n#3 {main}\n thrown in C:\\www\\thorastrup\\client_app\\sdk-1.5.14\\lib\\requestcore\\requestcore.class.php on line 829
```

I simply don't understand this error and would be glad if anyone could tell me with was wrong? (I am running apache on Windows 7 with php-5)

Comment: The code is a file from the samples folder in the SDK: "cli-s3_get_urls_for_uploads.php". I just downloaded the sdk and configured the config.inc.php file with my credentials and enabled curl :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://engin.bzzzt.biz/2012/02/02/windows-php-curl-ssl-certificate-problem/

As for the CA-bundle file, you can follow those instructions or just download it from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem